# Undefined control sequence error in using spy TikZ library

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, spy

My minimal working example is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
%\usepackage[font=normal,caption=false]{subfig}
%\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary[shadings]

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Koch curve}{
  \rule{F -> F-F++F-F}}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Sierpinski triangle}{
  \rule{F -> G-F-G}
  \rule{G -> F+G+F}}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Fractal plant}{
  \rule{X -> F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X}
  \rule{F -> FF}}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Hilbert curve}{
  \rule{L -> +RF-LFL-FR+}
  \rule{R -> -LF+RFR+FL-}}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{cccc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,yellow,magnification=2,size=4cm, connect spies}]
 \draw [green!50!black, rotate=90]
    [l-system={Fractal plant, axiom=X, order=6, step=2pt, angle=25}]
    lindenmayer system;
    \spy on (2.4,8) in node [right] at (2,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=2,size=4.5cm, connect spies}]
    \shadedraw [bottom color=white, top color=red!80, draw=red!80!black]
    [l-system={Hilbert curve, axiom=L, order=5, step=8pt, angle=90}]
    lindenmayer system;
    \spy on (5.9,1.3) in node [right] at (9,7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\\
\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=3.5,size=4.5cm, connect spies}]
\shadedraw [top color=white, bottom color=blue!80, draw=blue!80!black]
[l-system={Sierpinski triangle, step=2pt, angle=60, axiom=F, order=8}]
lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\spy on (5.7,1.3) in node [right] at (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
&

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shadedraw[shading=color wheel][spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=3.5,size=4.5cm, connect spies}]
[l-system={Koch curve, step=2pt, angle=60, axiom=F++F++F, order=4}]
lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\spy on (4,6) in node [left] at (1,7);
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

The error I am getting is as follows.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...] lindenmayer system -- cycle; \spy 
                                                  on (4,6) in node [left] at...
l.68  \end{tabular}}

? 
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 4 in font nullfont!
```

Comment: Could you please minimize the code as much as possible! I am getting an undefined control sequence \end{tabular} here.

Comment: The error can at least be reduced to just the last of your four `tikzpictures`, though i can't see yet why that does not work. The others produce nice spies here. Please reduce your MWE. You could of course provide a `spy`that works - and the last one that does not; though - interestingly - i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,decorations.fractals}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Koch curve}{
  \rule{F -> F-F++F-F}}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Sierpinski triangle}{
  \rule{F -> G-F-G}
  \rule{G -> F+G+F}}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Fractal plant}{
  \rule{X -> F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X}
  \rule{F -> FF}}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Hilbert curve}{
  \rule{L -> +RF-LFL-FR+}
  \rule{R -> -LF+RFR+FL-}}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{cccc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,yellow,magnification=2,size=4cm, connect spies}]
 \draw [green!50!black, rotate=90]
    [l-system={Fractal plant, axiom=X, order=6, step=2pt, angle=25}]
    lindenmayer system;
    \spy on (2.4,8) in node [right] at (2,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=2,size=4.5cm, connect spies}]
    \shadedraw [bottom color=white, top color=red!80, draw=red!80!black]
    [l-system={Hilbert curve, axiom=L, order=5, step=8pt, angle=90}]
    lindenmayer system;
    \spy on (5.9,1.3) in node [right] at (9,7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\\
\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=3.5,size=4.5cm, connect spies}]
\shadedraw [top color=white, bottom color=blue!80, draw=blue!80!black]
[l-system={Sierpinski triangle, step=2pt, angle=60, axiom=F, order=8}]
lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\spy on (5.7,1.3) in node [right] at (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
&

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=3.5,size=4.5cm, connect spies}]
\shadedraw[shading=color wheel]
[l-system={Koch curve, step=2pt, angle=60, axiom=F++F++F, order=4}]
lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\spy on (4,6) in node [left] at (1,7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabular}}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, your `compat=1.11` did not work (MacTeX 2015), but nevertheless If you look at your last `tikzpicture` you accidentally put the spy-introduction needed for the `spy` command *after* your `shadedraw`. Changing these yields

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=3.5,size=4.5cm, connect spies}]
\shadedraw[shading=color wheel]
[l-system={Koch curve, step=2pt, angle=60, axiom=F++F++F, order=4}]
lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\spy on (4,6) in node [left] at (1,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which compiles on my side (nevertheless, the spy is off and just magnifies white).